# Why do eVars register so many Nones?

Tags: adobe-analytics

I have some eVars that are registering a huge number of Nones.

These variables are set at the same time a corresponding traffic variable is set, for instance:

s.prop20 = someValue;

s.eVar20 = someValue;

When I give a check in Omniture, I see something like:

**prop20**

1. someValue1     |      12
2. someValue2     |        9
3. someValue3     |        5

.......

**eVar20**

1. None               |    1987
2. someValue1     |      12
3. someValue2     |        9
4. someValue3     |        5

.......

I'm very confuse about that. One hypotheses of mine is that the variable eVar20 is created even when it is not set, is there a way to avoid this Nones?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has everything to do with how the attribution and expiration works differently between eVars and props.

Props do not have any attribution/expiration options.  They are designed as 'traffic variables' and therefore only relate to the hit of data they were defined on.

eVars have flexible options for attribution (most recent, linear, original) and expiration (visit, 30 days etc).

As such what you're seeing is a default reporting option whereby when the metric you're looking at was recorded the 'none' value just states that there was no active eVar at that time.

Let me know if any of this is unclear.

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks a lot for your answer.
I strongly believe that this is the right answer.